# USPS Shipping API Standard Post Machinable tag

Tags: email, usps, postal

Ok so I've been trying to days now to figure out how to use the USPS shipping API to get the shipping rate of a package under the service "Standard Post".  I can do media mail, priority mail and first class but every time I try to do "Standard Post" I get this error:

> Machinable value must be 'True' or 'False' for service type Retail Gound and service type All.

If I then add either True or False I now get this error:

> The element 'Package' has invalid child element 'Machinable'. List of possible elements expected: 'ZipOrigination'.

Here is the request that I've been toying with:

```html
https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=RateV4&XML=<RateV4Request USERID="(omitted)">

<Package ID="standard"> 
<Service>Standard Post</Service> 
<FirstClassMailType>PARCEL</FirstClassMailType>
<Machinable>True</Machinable>
<ZipOrigination>44121</ZipOrigination> 
<ZipDestination>99352</ZipDestination> 
<Pounds>6</Pounds> 
<Ounces>8</Ounces> 
<Container>VARIABLE</Container> 
<Size>LARGE</Size> 
<Width>17</Width> 
<Length>13</Length> 
<Height>11</Height> 
<Girth>1</Girth> 
</Package>


</RateV4Request>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample request:

```
XML=<RateV4Request USERID=""><Revision>3</Revision><Package ID="0"><Service>PRIORITY</Service><ZipOrigination>22201</ZipOrigination><ZipDestination>26301</ZipDestination><Pounds>8</Pounds><Ounces>2</Ounces><Container></Container><Width>2</Width><Length>3</Length><Height>5</Height><Girth>1</Girth><Machinable>FALSE</Machinable></Package></RateV4Request>
```